# Probability basketball

Tags: probability, statistics

I got the following question :

> Estimate roughly the probability of a full-time draw in an even basketball
> game with 200 in expected points

In a very simple model we can assume that there are 200 points and each of them has a 50 percent of going either to team one or 50 percent to team two. Then we can model it as binomial distribution with n=200, and p=0.5 and getting a draw would be k=100, that then we can use the probability mass function to find the probability.

My question is if there is another method to calculate this probability?

Comment: If this is meant to capture a real game, I'd say that model was wildly unrealistic.

Comment: Though I have to admit it yields a pretty decent answer (to my surprise).  I get about $5.63\%$ this way  while looking at actual NBA data shows that ties in regulation  occur about $6.3\%$ of the time.

Comment: @lulu yes, it is very unrealistic but can't find another way to model it.

Comment: If you are interested in basketball statistics, I'd use basketball data.  [here](https://www.boydsbets.com/nba-key-numbers/) for instance is data that makes it appear that the distribution has a higher variance than your binomial model would suggest.  I suggest fitting this to a normal, and then using that normal.

Comment: To be precise:  your binomial model would predict that more than $11\%$ of games should be decided by $1$ point, but the data is nowhere near that.

Comment: @lulu That is interesting. To be honest I was given this question as a home assignment with no attached data, so I am trying by built a model without any kind of data.

Comment: You can't.  Sports statistics is a fascinating subject, but not a simple one.

Comment: @lulu That it's true.

Comment: If you assumed each team's score was iid Poisson distributed with mean $100$ then you would get $0.0282$.  Your binomial result is about double this partly because the margin between the two teams must be even in your binomial model.  (@lulu - the $11\%$ corresponds to a *margin* of $2$ either way)

Comment: @Henry How is 0.0282 occur? With which parameters?

Comment: @alanwatt: $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \left(\dfrac{100^ne^{-100}}{n!}\right)^2 = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{100^{2n}e^{-200}}{(n!)^2}$ or using  R  `sum(dpois(0:10000, 100)^2)`